# Return custom Tuple of value by executing an SQL command?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am building a **C#/WPF** application and I found that my code would look better if I use the DbContext class with this function **ExecuteStoreQuery**

However, not always my select queries  return an object of type present in my EDMX model.

For example I have a query like

```
"SELECT str1, str2 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id= {0}"
```

where str1 and str2 are of type string(varchar(50)).

I tried something like this

```
ObjectResult<SqlTwoStringsClass> sqlResult = myDbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<SqlTwoStringsClass>(sql_Select_From_MY_TABLE);

foreach (SqlTwoStringsClass item in sqlResult)
{
    Utils.printToConsole(item.text1 + ", " + item.text2);
}
```

where **sql_Select_From_MY_TABLE** is an sql string:

```
 "SELECT DISTINCT [str1], [str2] FROM [GP].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] WHERE ID = {0} AND ID2 IS NOT NULL";
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp
{
    class SqlTwoStringsClass
    {
        public string text1;
        public string text2;
    }
}
```

But when I print the result, the two strings are empty.

I also tried something like this:

```
ObjectResult<Tuple<string, string>> sqlResult = myDbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Tuple<string, string>>(sql_Select_From_MY_TABLE, someID);
```

But when I execute it, it fails with exception that the Tuple was not initialized.

How can I return two strings from a query? What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: The LINQ-to-Entities query **do not always have to return entity objects.** You may choose some of the properties of an entity as a result (projection). And the proper way is to use this ability. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class needs to have properties with the same names as the columns from the database for the framework to be able to match them. In your case you can either modify the SQL or the `SqlTwoStringsClass` property names and also have to turn the `SqlTwoStringsClass` fields into properties using `get; set;`

```
SELECT DISTINCT [str1] as text1, [str2] as text2
FROM [GP].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] WHERE ID = {0} AND ID2 IS NOT NULL
```

You also need to turn the fields of the class into properties:

```
public class SqlTwoStringsClass
{
    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string text2 { get; set; }
}
```